# Statistical significance of stock portfolio returns?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I bought 3 stocks on 1/1/2013: ABC, ACME, WRAM.  By 3/1/2013, I earned a 10% return.

During the same period, the S&P 500 returned 5%.

Is my superior performance statistically significant?

Comment: As stated, you have N of 1 and statistical significance is meaningless. But actually, you have time series data (your portfolio and the S&P performed on each of the 60 or so days that the market was open between 1/1 and now. You should look into time series methods.

Comment: Short answer: No. :-)

Comment: @cardinal - I'd love to hear the long answer ;)

Comment: @PeterFlom - that's a helpful clue.  Do you know any formulas where I can plug in two time series and receive a p-value?

Comment: Ultimately, I'm looking for a formula that I can plug information into.

Comment: Time series is a whole sub-specialty in statistics and not one I am well versed in. I added the "time series" tag so perhaps some of our experts will chime in

Comment: I'm assuming the background to this question is 'I think I'm onto a great stock-picking technique, I want to know it it works' - is it?  Well, you could say H0 = "mean of returns = s&p500", H1 = "mean of returns > s&p500", assume returns are t-distribited, plug the numbers in, and check if p < 0.05. You could goose up the model by incorporating known info about correlations/fat tails. But what will happen if you use this technique to find a winning strategy is that you'll try quite a few strategies, and one will pop out as p < 0.05 by chance alone. So I'd look at cross-validation/OOS tests.

Comment: Some of the ideas here might be useful for you: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/955/separating-the-wheat-from-the-chaff-what-quant-methods-separate-skillful-manage